# How can I add a footer to precisely one page such that there is a bar over the footer?

Tags: header-footer

How can I add a footer to precisely one page (namely, to the first page) such that there is a bar over the footer?

I see some people say to use the user package fancyheadings. However this changed the section layout, and adds something to every page.

Comment: Please give us a minimal example of code to work with. Also a bit more detail. Is this really part of a title page as opposed to a genuine footer? Right now, your question can be answered only by guessing a whole bunch of stuff which will likely turn out to be wrong, rendering any solution based on that guesswork useless to you. Help us to help you: ask us a question somebody might be able to answer satisfactorily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `fancyheadings` has been obsolete for several years. Actually, doing `\usepackage{fancyheadings}` will simply do the same as `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`.

The trick is to define a special style for the first page and emit `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% emulate the plain style
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% a rule at the bottom
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{All rights reserved}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\lipsum[1-20] % fill some pages

\end{document}
```

[image]